# When COPYing to Redshift, how to deal with special characters in a CSV?

Tags: csv, amazon-redshift

I am using a COPY with ACCEPTINVCHARS to load a CSV into Amazon Redshift.

Unfortunately I get errors like

```
Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x69 found at location 129
```

However, if I try to use the ESCAPE option as well, I get the exception

```
CSV is not compatible with ESCAPE
```

What am I supposed to do in order to COPY this into Redshift? I'm fine if the chars get replaced with ? or whatever.

Comment: What's the exact character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the header as the headers might not be of the same datatype as your fields.
Use IGNOREHEADER AS

Refer to the forum for more details,
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=557452

Comment: please go through the forum link, there are multiple possibilities based on the actual data.

Comment: What if you are inserting data using `INSERT INTO` query and not COPY command, how to include "acceptinvchars" in that case?

Answer (score 0):

For future generations, "CSV is not compatible with ESCAPE" is probably right but you don't actually need the CSV keyword to load CSV, so it's worth trying to remove the CSV keyword from your copy command.